# Azure Functions publishing

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions

Firstly I would like to describe my local project structure. I have three Azure Functions v2. Locally each function have separate project. The fourth project is library which functions are using.

I would like to publish those functions into one function on Azure ( one App Service). And there's the issue occurs.

Let's start with an example. Let's say the function names are : A, B, C.

Firstly I publish functions in order: A, B, C. Then I've change something in function B, and publish only B. Then the function A, and C are not working.
I've must publish all functions to work again. 
My first thought was package incompatibility and resolved that. But the issue still occurs. The web publish file does not contains any info about any additional packages/dlls.

Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intention itself that publishing several Function projects to one Function app is incorrect.

See the [official guidance](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Deploying-Function-Apps-vs-individual-Functions).

> In most scenarios, the unit of deployment should be the Function App, and not individual functions. Deploying a Function App is essentially identical to deploying a Web App.

Locally one Function project represents exactly one complete Function app, so one Function app should host only one published Function project. Otherwise we may see inconsistent behavior after publishing which results from content overwritten and so on.

My suggestion is to put functions together in one project, merging usually doesn't bring trouble unless there are specific [host settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json) for each project.

Comment: I agree with Jerry's suggestions. Just to give a hint that when merging all functions into one project, you can actually merge only their definitions and separate the code for each function in separate Class Library project. Eventually, you will keep your current structure almost intact.